# SQLAlchemy transparent access to same table accross databases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using MySQL and SQLAlchemy, and I have two databases with identical tables, but different data. Database db1 is used for "hot" data, therefore has much better performance, and db2 for archival. I won't ever need to perform joins across databases, since all related data is moved accordingly.

Whenever I insert or update new data, it goes into db1, and db2 is basically read only, so it's simple for me to have two engines and use a db1 session whenever I commit. However, is there any simple way for SQLAlchemy to transparently query data from both and consolidate the results? For instance, when I add a new row, it always goes into db1, but when I query one with the primary key, I'd like it to search the tables in both db1 and db2 without having to refactor all queries in my code.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using master/slave database replication? That seems like a perfect solution here. Doing this at the ORM/app level seems clunky.

Comment: It has nothing to do with replication. The databases have identical schema, but different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Horizontal Sharding](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/horizontal_shard.html) extension, an example usage of which is provided in the [documentation](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/_modules/examples/sharding/attribute_shard.html).  This allows you to use a special ShardedSession which uses various dispatch functions to decide which database to talk to.

```
def shard_chooser(mapper, instance, clause=None):
    """return a shard key based on the instance being handled"""

def id_chooser(query, ident):
    """return a shard key based on primary key"""

def query_chooser(query):
    """return a shard key based on the query"""

create_session = sessionmaker(class_=ShardedSession)
create_session.configure(
    shards={
        # map keys to engines
    },
    shard_chooser=shard_chooser,
    id_chooser=id_chooser,
    query_chooser=query_chooser
)
```